# Cleaning up Rails backtrace for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, stack-trace

Rails backtrace/stacktrace can be huge in logs and require a lot of tedious scrolling back. Is there any way to reduce the crud to focus on typical application errors?

The solution probably involves configuring [BacktraceCleaner](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html), but its docs are minimal and examples are scarce elsewhere. I also wonder if there are any gems that might have enhanced config (e.g. collapsing together a list of errors from the same module); but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Could you give an example? What are typical application errors?

Comment: I haven't got an example here but just the usual error in a controller which has dozens of "boilerplate" references to ActiveSupport and other libraries. Also includes Rack filters like New Relic gem, all of which just add noise.